# How to over ride the aria-label of KendoUI Table wizard control as part of Accessibility bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, accessibility

How to customize the aria-label on mouse hover of the Table wizard. I have highlighted the dropdown of the table wizard.

[image]

NVDA/JAWS screen reader is reading it as something like "Units px". So I want to override the aria-label text of width as "Width units px" and "Height units px" for Height dropdown px selection. Please let me know if this is possible.

Below is the URL for example text editor. Open the link [enter link description here](https://dojo.telerik.com/uTEtAYoN/3). Then click on "Create a table" button. Then the below above popup will open.

Comment: I don’t know Kendo Ui so don’t know if it has options to change attributes. If not,  in general if you want to change an HTML attribute you’d run some JavaScript onload but you have tagged CSS not JS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you see any other alternatives rather than writing JavaScript code to run on Onload? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing loads in your Kendo example. Kendo components out of the box are pretty accessible so it looks like you've made your own component here? If so you can either labelledby the dropdown or custom aria label; hard to tell without actually seeing your code (post that here).

Comment: I have updated the link. Please check now. I would like to override the aria-label for the highlighted dropdown.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Do you have any recommendation based on the updated link above? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You'll have to do it manually. Stick your code on the `change` event. Below is an example of changing the `aria-label`. This example is a blanket change, you'll have to pin point the change yourself but this should get you started. The idea is to find the `span` of the label you want to change. The example below changes the label to "One label to rule them all", from "Units". Try the code below on the DOJO.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<script>
  
  $("#editor").kendoEditor({
    messages: {
      tableWizard: "Table Wizard"
    },
    change: function() {
      var $spans = $("body").find("span.k-picker.k-dropdownlist.k-picker-solid.k-picker-md.k-rounded-md");
      
      $spans.each(function() {
        $(this).attr("aria-label", "One label to rule them all");
      });
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```